# になろうと言った and になると言った

Tags: grammar

What are the differences between になろうと言った and になると言った ?
[image]

Comment: is there an image attached to this? I only see a broken image link...

Comment: Yes, There's a image, my friend. Try to click on this link instead ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPNsU.jpg

Comment: Thanks, it appears the internal network at work is blocking the image...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (お前は私に)「～～ volitional auxiliary う/よう」と言った。
>   (お前は私に)「～～ plain form of a verb」と言った。

I would *normally* interpret the former as "You said, 'Let's do ~~'," i.e. "You suggested that we should do ~~," and the latter as "You said, 'I will do ~~'," i.e. "You said that you would do ~~."

So I think 「お前は『人間に**なる**』と言った」 means "You said you would be human," and 「お前は『人間に**なろう**』と言った」 would be interpreted as "You suggested that we should become human."

Examples:

- 彼は(私に)東京に行**こう**と言った。 He suggested we go to Tokyo.
- 彼は(私に)東京に行**く**と言った。 He told me that he was going to Tokyo.

Answer (score 1):

The first expresses intent to try '~ said s/he will try become ~'.
The second is '~ said it will become ~'

Comment: I have no idea who the hell has thumbed down yours (despite of my thumb up ). Your answer is a good answer. I wish I could accept it also.

Comment: meh, it happens. Its a cut-throat world out here where you take your time to offer free help to others in need :)

Comment: But that is not big deal. I'm going to thumb up your other questions. I Just want say thank.